# pgAdmin III An error has occurred: Error connecting to the server: to rails webrick server in development enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

I'm building my first rails app with PostgreSQL, everthing has been going fine but now I need to get direct access to the database.  I was hoping to use a GUI like pgAdmin III but I'm not sure how to connect it to my development database?

I've tried the following but I'm only guessing as I could find no guides

In my **database.yml** file I have

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: ross
  password:
```

in **pgAdmin III - New Server Registration - Properties**

```
Name: myapp_development
Host: 127.0.0.1
port: 3000
SSL:
Maintenance DB: postgres
username: ross
password: 
Store password: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what error you are seeing when trying to connect?. At a guess I'd say port `3000` seems unlikely.... postgres default port is `5432`.

Comment: that worked but I get a new error `Error connecting to the server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`.  I never set up the database with a password when I installed PostgreSQL

Comment: Sounds like you probably haven't setup postgres fully just yet. You might be able to connect using user: `postgres` without a password (but this totally depends on how you installed postgres). I'd recormend marking this question as answered, then taking a look at the [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and/or following some setup tutorials online then ask a new question if you get stuck again.